# How can I parse data from a string with this format: 1 Gt 500.85?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, fstream

I have about 100 lines of text.  Each line has the following format: `1 Gt 1.003` The `Gt` will change and will be from 1 to 3 characters long.  How can I parse this line and store the `Gt` as a string, the `1.003` as a double, and discard the `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace std;
int discardInt;
string strInput;
double dblInput;

vector<string> strings;
vector<double> doubles;

ifstream infile("filename.txt"); //open your file

while(infile >> discard >> strInput >> dblInput) {
  //now discard stores the value 1, which you don't use;
  //strInput stores Gt or other 1-3 character long string;
  //dblInput stores the double

 //operations to store the values that are now in strInput and dblInput
 //for example, to push the values into a vector:
   strings.push_back(strInput);
   doubles.push_back(dblInput);

}

infile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty normal stuff.

```
ifstream file(...);
string line;
while (getline(file, line)
{
    istringstream buf(line);
    int dummy;
    string tag;
    double val;
    buf >> dummy >> tag >> val;
}
```

`tag` will be "Gt", `val` will be 1.003